# How to load a CSS file based on a URL or client?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, stylesheet, sencha-touch-2.3

I have two CSS files in my Sencha touch application. Lets call them `A.css` and `B.css`. Based on the URL I want the application to load different CSS.

Lets say URL 1 is `www.website.com/#1` so for this I would like to load `A.css`. similarly URL 2 is `www.website.com/#2` so for this I would like to load `B.css`

Is it possible to load CSS dynamically based on the URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript Regex for this.

Very easy method:

```
    // For www.website.com/#1
    if (/www.website.com\/#1/.test(window.location.href)) {
        /* Your Code Here For Loading Css */
    }

    // For www.website.com/#2
    if (/www.website.com\/#1/.test(window.location.href)) {
        /* Your Code Here For Loading Css */
    }
```

I hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follow JavaScript code to load CSS dynamically for your requirement:

```
if (window.location == "http://www.website.com/#1") {
     LoadCSS("A.css")
}
else if(window.location == "http://www.website.com/#2") {
     LoadCSS("B.css")
}

function LoadCSS(filename) {
     var fileref = document.createElement("link");
     fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
     fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
     fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have one template available for 2 URLs. Loading CSS using JavaScript is a pretty bad practice because it's slow and it's giving the user a bad experience since nothing is initially styled.

Anyway you can use the append function to add the CSS to the head tag.

```
$('head')
  .append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')
  .attr('href', 'your_stylesheet_url') );
```

And for the URL itself simply use the JavaScript `window.location` like so:

```
if (window.location == "#1url") {
    // load the A.css using the append function like above
}
```

Comment: Although you made an effort giving an answer, he did not ask for a jquery answer. (see tags)

Comment: By the way, Jquery is a cross-platform Javascript library. Your argument is invalid, Javascript is never a bad practice and is presumably not a bad practice.

Still, you are using Javascript when using Jquery.

Comment: the tags have been edited then. jquery has been one of the tags before. and loading css on domready using js is a bad practice. css should be always loaded before any javascript for obvious usability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Get hashtag value from URL and then depending on value change the link for CSS.

To get hashtag value:

```
$url = "www.website.com/#1";
$params = parse_url($url);

$value = $params['fragment'];
```

This will give you hashtag value, then depending on value link CSS file in header:

```
<?php if ($value == 1) { ?>
<link href="A.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } else { ?>
<link href="B.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php } ?>
```