# Add css only when url is https://mywebsite.com/my-account/return

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I want to load the following `CSS` only when window url is **https://mywebsite.com/my-account/return**

CSS:

```
<style>.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr{
    display: table-row !important;}

.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td{
    display: table-cell !important;}

.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td:before{
    display: table-row !important;}</style>
```

Comment: Then don't load it. You need to specify your situation and your requirements, else no one can help you.

Comment: Please provide more details regarding want you want to achieve and how, with the information provided is very difficult to help you. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860029/how-to-load-a-css-file-based-on-a-url-or-client, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load the style, try this with jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
      console.log(pageURL);
      if( pageURL == 'https://mywebsite.com/my-account/return') {
          $('head').append('<style>.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr{\
    display: table-row !important;}\
.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td{\
    display: table-cell !important;}\
.shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td:before{\
    display: table-row !important;}</style>');
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add those display rules to a class and then add that class to the body dynamically based on the `window.location`.

Your CSS rules would look something like this (note the new `.mywebsite-com-my-account-return` class):

```
<style>
    .mywebsite-com-my-account-return .shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr {
        display: table-row !important;
    }

    .mywebsite-com-my-account-return .shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td {
        display: table-cell !important;
    }

    .mywebsite-com-my-account-return .shop table.shop_table.my_account_orders>tbody>tr>td:before {
        display: table-row !important;
    }
</style>
```

Then your Javascript would look like this:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href === "https://mywebsite.com/my-account/return") {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("mywebsite-com-my-account-return")
    }
</script>
```